# How do I simulate a slow Meteor publication?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to simulate a publication doing a bunch of work and taking a long time to return a cursor.

My publish method has a forced sleep (using a future), but the app always displays only

## Loading...

Here's the publication:

```
Meteor.publish('people', function() {
  Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
  var future = new Future();

  //simulate long pause
  setTimeout(function() {
    // UPDATE: coding error here. This line needs to be
    //   future.return(People.find());
    // See the accepted answer for an alternative, too:
    //   Meteor._sleepForMs(2000);
    return People.find();
  }, 2000);

  //wait for future.return
  return future.wait();
});
```

And the router:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.map(function() {
  return this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    waitOn: function() {
      return [Meteor.subscribe('people')];
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        'people': People.find()
      };
    }
  });
});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

Full source code: https://gitlab.com/meonkeys/meteor-simulate-slow-publication

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the undocumented `Meteor._sleepForMs` function like so:

```
Meteor.publish('people', function() {
  Meteor._sleepForMs(2000);
  return People.find();
});
```

Comment: Handy, thanks! I updated my question to show the coding error I made, too.

Comment: Hint: don't try to look to `Meteor._sleepForMs` at the client, it's a server-only method.

Comment: Question: This worked for me, thanks. But only once. I guess after the first load the publication is cached on the client. Is there a way to simulate a slower connection on every refresh? (Or at least to test it again?)

Comment: Yeah that's the expected behavior. Once the docs are subscribed to, you'll hit the client cache for them. In order to see the delay again you'd need to stop the subscription and start it again (or refresh the page, etc.).

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. But even on refresh the collection is almost instantly there. (Note: I have autopublish removed). You get the delay again, when you refresh?

Comment: Yes. A refresh of the page will kill all active subscriptions on the client. I'd recommend adding a console.log to see if the publisher is getting called. If you still can't figure it out, post a new question with the associated code.