# Meteor Iron-Router: why isn't this routing setup (with waitOn and data functions) working correctly?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Using Iron-Router 1.0.3 and Meteor 1.0.

I have this route defined:

```js
Router.route('audit', {
    path: '/audit/:audit_id/',
    template: 'audit',
    data: function() {
        audit = Audits.findOne({_id: this.params.audit_id});
        lineitems = LineItems.find(JSON.parse(audit.query));
        return {
            audit: audit,
            lineitems: lineitems
        }
    },
    waitOn: function () {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('audits'),
            Meteor.subscribe('lineitems', this.params.audit_id),
        ]
    }
});
```

Objects in the Audits collection have the following structure:

```
{
    _id: 'timestamped-id-that-I-generate',
    name: 'some name',
    query: JSON.stringify({'$and': [list of query conditions here]})
}
```

When I go to this route I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
```

But if I go to my browser console, I can examine the Audits collections and I see that the Audit object with the appropriate _id and query exists as expected.

Incidentally, the publish method for the lineitems on the server side will simply look up the same audit object and publish the line items that match it's query.

(I have to serialize the query back and forth via JSON because otherwise the query object would contain field names that violate MongoDB regulations.)

Comment: Hmm, I've noticed that the route seems to work when I call Router.go(), but doesn't seem to work if I just go to the URL directly.

Comment: I'm really not sure about it, but try to log `audit` in the console after you got it, and log `this.params.audit_id` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, Iron Router's `data` hook may run multiple times when a route is evaluated. You can assume it will run once before the subscriptions are ready, and again afterward. Because it will run prior to your subscriptions being ready, you need to assume that `Audits.findOne` will return `undefined` at least once. You have two choices:

1. Check for `this.ready()` in your `data` hook:

```js
data: function() {
  if (this.ready()) {
    audit = Audits.findOne({_id: this.params.audit_id});
    lineitems = LineItems.find(JSON.parse(audit.query));
    return {audit: audit, lineitems: lineitems};
  }
}
```

2. Use a [guard](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards):

```js
data: function() {
  audit = Audits.findOne({_id: this.params.audit_id});
  if (audit && audit.query) {
    lineitems = LineItems.find(JSON.parse(audit.query));
    return {audit: audit, lineitems: lineitems};
  }
}
```

A combination of the two may actually be appropriate if: (a) you don't have any audits, or (b) not all audits have a query.

Comment: Is this a field, where it will improve, or it is designed this way, and should everyone check for readiness?

Comment: It's designed that way, so you probably need to do one of the two choices above if you are returning data based on a fetch/findOne.

Comment: `waitOn` is to signal, that I *need* the mentioned subscriptions, right? So, then why would `data` get called, when those subscriptions are not ready? Or, if I am wrong, what signals `this.ready`, and why `data` get called, when it's not ready?

Comment: http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial#waiting-for-a-subscription states data is run, only when subscriptions are ready

Comment: It's possible that is true if you add a `loadingTemplate` - see the plugins section of the [docs](https://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/). Note that IR has changed a lot since that blog post was written so I'd recommend just experimenting with it and see what you find. You can [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818893/how-do-i-simulate-a-slow-meteor-publication) to simulate a slow publication.